# Rails 3 and Thin. Is there a way to execute a file after thin starts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thin

I currently have a rails 3.2 app that I am going to use thin as a web server for. I haven't found a way or know if what I am even attempting is possible which is why I came here to ask. What i'm trying to do is after I start my rails app with the usual bundle exec thin start to afterward execute a ruby file/script to load up another web event based mini application(pure ruby non web framework) that will uses the same server/ data store as the main rails app. Is there such a hook either with thin configs or rails start up configs to accomplish such a thing?

-edit-

to clarify, the mini application is within the rails app in its own directory, it is not an external app which is why it will share resources.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html)? It is a tool used for describing and launching all the individual processes your application requires (potentially covering both your main web server, thin, and the secondary Ruby process you mentioned). You would just install Foreman, then write a [`Procfile`](http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/) describing both processes to run at startup.

Comment: I haven't, thanks for the the informative answer! I"ll go give that a go and see how that works.